# Mysterious C++ declaration

Tags: c++

Sorry for the dumb question (I'm a total C++ noob), but what does

`int x[101010];`

declare? Is it list, a vector et cetera? And what is the meaning of 101010? I have never seen a declaration like this.

Comment: An array of `int` with 101010 elements

Comment: Got it. Should I delete the question or let it be?

Comment: You can let it be, or post an answer yourself.

Comment: `x` is `variable` of `int` Array, number between **[** and **]** is count of elements.

Comment: I will start a close vote. I think your question is justified, but with this title and content it is unlikley that anyone with the same issue will find it, and I don't know a good change to amend it. Also there is a general FAQ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At *block* scope, `int x[101010];` declares a *uninitialised* array with `101010` elements.

At *global* scope, the effect is similar but the elements are set to `0`.

Note that if you had written `int x[010101];`, then you would have created `4161` elements as a leading `0` denotes an *octal* literal in C++.

In C++, a good rule of thumb is to use a `std::vector` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Made a *tiny* fix, hope you don't mind. Function scope is for [the things that we dare not mention](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.funscope).